# Prove that $ \lim_{n\to\infty} n(\sqrt[n]{x} -1) =\ln x $

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Suppose we have function sequence:
$f_n(x) = n(\sqrt[n]{x} -1)$

$ x\in [1,2] $

How to prove that
$ \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x) =\ln x $  ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $\frac{e^x - 1}{x}\to 1$ as $x\to 0$. Since $x^{1/n} -1 = e^{1/n ln x} - 1$, $\cdots$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit can be recognized as a derivative:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n(x^{1/n}-1) = \lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac{x^y-1}{y-0} = f'(0) = \ln(x),$$
where $f(y) = x^y$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac x n\right)^n.$$